# Creating an NSString pointer

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Consider:

```
  NSString*test2=[[NSString alloc]init];

test2=@"yo";
NSString *test= test2;
NSLog(@"test: %@ test2: %@",test, test2);
test2=@"what the?";
NSLog(@"test: %@ test2: %@",test, test2);
```

Output:

```
2012-11-14 09:50:26.720 testt[693:c07] test: yo test2: yo
2012-11-14 09:50:26.721 testt[693:c07] test: yo test2: what the?
```

How does one make `test` a true pointer, such that when `test2` changes, so does `test`?

Comment: You need to use a pointer to a pointer since 'test' is already a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSString *test2` is already a pointer. You'd want to make `test` pointer to a pointer (double `*`), and assign `test2`'s address to it using `&` prefix then access the value using `*` prefix. I suck at explaining this so here is the code:

```
test2=@"yo";
NSString **test= &test2;
NSLog(@"test: %@ test2: %@", *test, test2);
test2=@"what the?";
NSLog(@"test: %@ test2: %@", *test, test2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You *have* created a "true pointer", the problem is that the statement:

```
test2 = @"What the?";
```

is creating a new string object and assigning the pointer to the new string into the variable `test2`, `test` still contains the old pointer.

You could create a pointer to a pointer to solve this problem. Alternatively you could use an `NSMutableString` and then only use the `NSMutableString` methods to change (mutate) the string rather than reassigning new values to the `test` and `test2` variables.

The following would be the `NSMutableString` version of your example:

```
NSString *test2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"yo"];       
NSString *test = test2;

NSLog(@"test: %@ test2: %@", test, test2);

[test2 setString:@"what the?"];

NSLog(@"test: %@ test2: %@", test, test2);
```

Which produces the output:

```
2012-11-14 10:06:27.231 Untitled 2[592:707] test: yo test2: yo
2012-11-14 10:06:27.232 Untitled 2[592:707] test: what the? test2: what the?
```

---

`NSString`s have some extra syntactic sugar in Objective-C so that both the following have the same effect (although what happens in the background could be completely different or the same).

```
NSString *test = [NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
NSString *test = @"Hello World";
```

Both of these statements create a new immutable (unchangeable) string.  Creating an `NSString` using the statement `[NSString alloc] init]` creates an empty string which is usually not what you want to do.

---

This means that, in your example where the first two lines are:

```
NSString*test2=[[NSString alloc]init];
test2=@"yo";
```

The first line is unnecessary as you are creating a string object and placing the pointer in `test2` and then immediately overwriting that pointer with a pointer to the string created by `@"yo"`.  If you aren't using ARC this would cause a memory leak as the string created by `[[NSString alloc] init]` hasn't been released.  However, `NSString` doesn't really work the same as other objects so rather than leaking memory it would probably be more correct to say you are wasting memory"

Comment: NSMutableString might probably be a better solution, yeah. I wonder what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: I am merely trying to achieve an understanding of how strings and pointers work in Objective C. This is an exercise more than anything.

Comment: Regarding your point about "extra syntactic sugar" - the explicit call to `init` in the first is now creating ownership, while the second, the `=@"yo"` is not, thus memory leaks would be a non issue with the second approach, whereas the first runs risks if you don't `release` in non-Arc environment, right?

Comment: `NSString` is a bit odd in that immutable strings don't really follow the same retain/release cycle.  Using `retainCount` is a bad idea but in the case of an NSString `retainCount` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following:

```
NSString *test = &test2;
```

Comment: see @FilipRadelic's answer above -- it needs two stars, not one